# Modify contents in scrollable div keeping the position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div containing around 20 little divs inside, so that when you click on one, the big div is scrolled to center the small one; then its margins are increased. Problem is, when the margins are increased, the small div is pushed downwards, because the scroll position stays in the same place. I can fire another event to compensate the movement, but it doesn't look pretty, there's race conditions and the effects are no exact opposites.

Is there a way to keep the div centered in the scroll and then push the neighbors away from it?

Comment: Can you post an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can better help you.

Comment: For some reason it does not work (i.e. doesn't render the scrollbars for the columns), but here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Atbxf/2/